# Regression modelling, t-statistics, and $H_0$

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, least-squares

When I use t-statistics in OLS regression modelling to determine if the coefficient of any independent variables is statistically significant, I hope for a t-stat value that is higher than 2 (or what have you).

When I use t-stats to check if my hypothesis is correct or not, I accept the $H_0$ if the t stat is *less* than 2 (or what have you).

Why is it that the t-statistic is used one way to validate one thing, but another way to validate another thing?

Comment: This probably essentially answers the question, but testing if a variable is significant *is* a hypothesis test. Generally, you want to reject $H_0$ to accept $H_a$, which is what you are doing with a high t-statistic value for a variable in regression. You would reject $H_0: \beta=0$ if the t-statistic is *more* than 2, which implies that the regression coefficient $\beta$ is significantly different from 0.

Comment: I wouldn't say you accept H0, you just don't reject it. 'by default' you are at H0 (that's why it's called H0) and if you have enough evidence in favor of H1 you switch to H1. You only test H1, not H0.

Comment: NOTE:  Be careful.  The critical value for a t-test (at 0.05 significance level) is around 2 when you have plenty of data, but if you don't have much data 2 won't be large enough.  For instance, the cutoff for 5 degrees of freedom (in simple linear regression, n = 7 observations) is 2.57.  For one degree of freedom (though I think I'd run if I saw a 1 degree of freedom regression) the cutoff is 12!

Answer (score 2):

Testing if a variable is significant *is* a hypothesis test. For a regression coefficient $\beta$, the hypotheses are:
$$H_0: \beta=0$$
$$H_a: \beta\ne0$$

Therefore, if a regression coefficient is deemed "significant", it is because the t-statistic was large enough to cross the threshold to reject $H_0$. This means that there is enough evidence to suggest that the regression coefficient is different from zero, so it could be an important variable in the model.

Also, tho_mi is right in the comment below your question, you don't really "accept" $H_0$. You typically write $H_0$ and $H_a$ in such a way that you **want** $H_a$ to be the truth in order to be interesting. It is (generally) uninteresting if a variable's regression coefficient is zero because then it has no impact on the model. The reason for this is that your calculations for the t-statistic rely on the assumption that $H_0$ is true. The p-value is the probability that, assuming $H_0$ is true, you randomly observed the value for $\hat\beta$.